# how do i debug a node.js app using heroku foreman?

Tags: debugging, node.js, heroku

i am new to heroku and node.js.  i have a small node.js app which i can start and run successfully on my local machine using FOREMAN from the heroku toolbelt.  i do not understand how to best debug the app, though.

i see that there is an eclipse debugger for node.js as well as the node-inspector project.  but i cant seem to make these work with FOREMAN.

```
foreman start
```

if it is not possible to debug an app started by foreman, what is the purpose of foreman?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of Foreman is to allow you to run complex applications, which may consist of several processes, easily. Check out the [author's blog post on Foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html):

> Lately I've noticed my web apps are getting complicated to run. My
>   apps no longer consist of a single web process; I usually have have
>   one or more types of background workers to run different types of jobs
>   and a clock process to handle scheduling. Splitting an app up in this
>   way is great for performance and scalability. The downside, however,
>   is that it becomes much more complicated to get the app and all of its
>   parts running.
>
> Foreman is an attempt to make this easier. Using foreman you can
>   declare the various processes that are needed to run your application
>   using a Procfile.

By leveraging Foreman, Heroku has made it so that you can essentially run any kind of process you want to--a Rails app, a Sinatra app, a Node.js app, or anything else--simply by specifying how to start it in your `Procfile`, which Foreman reads and executes.

Foreman also allows you to take this simple Procfile and export it to production environments using tools like Upstart and Init. It does not provide any debugging functionality (nor is it meant to).

Answer (score 12):

Just an addition, your Procfile could look like this:

```
web: node web.js
webDebug: node --debug-brk=5858 web.js`
```

So to start debugging you just call `foreman start webDebug`, you could call the configuration however you want.

The debugger will listen on port 5858 and you'll have to call your app from http://localhost:5100 instead of http://localhost:5000.

Comment: @Irina Could you please explain following lines "The debugger will listen on port 5858 and you'll have to call your app from http://localhost:5100 instead of http://localhost:5000." Thnx

Comment: @WitVault you not necessary switch the port, just be sure attach properly, like by default `npm debug localhost:5858` after you launch your app in debug mode.