# Running foreman start through visual studio code launch.json

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, foreman

Currently, I am running my solution by typing `foreman start` into the command line and that is working fine. I'm trying to debug my code using visual studio code. In order to do so, I have created a launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/package.json",

            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "start",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "externalConsole": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        }
    ]
}
```

I have created a tasks.json file to try to start the program from that point:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "start",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "--no-color"
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "test",
            "args": [],
            "isTestCommand": true
        },
        {
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "taskName": "start",
            "args": [
                "foreman",
                "start"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true
        }
    ]
}
```

When I run `foreman start` normally, I see this output:

```
$ foreman start
12:00:59 web.1          | started with pid 22641
12:00:59 workers.1      | started with pid 22642
12:00:59 intermediary.1 | started with pid 22643
12:01:00 web.1          | [INFO] Node app is running at localhost: 3777
```

If I debug in this current state, the output from the console is:

```
Failed to launch external program start --no-color.
spawn start ENOENT
```

If I change my program to point to gulp:

```
"program": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/gulp",
```

It gives me something a little more promising, but because it isn't foreman, it doesn't run everything I need.

```
node --debug-brk=16751 --nolazy node_modules/.bin/gulp 
Debugger listening on port 16751
[16:23:17] Using gulpfile ~/Git/backend/gulpfile.js
[16:23:17] Starting 'watch'...
[16:23:18] Finished 'watch' after 125 ms
[16:23:18] Starting 'default'...
[16:23:18] Finished 'default' after 13 μs
```

Does anyone know how to debug `foreman start` from visual studio code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will run `foreman start` as shell command. Press <kbd>F1</kbd>, type `Run Task`, <kbd>Enter</kbd> and select `development` task.

#### tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "foreman",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "taskName": "development",
            "args": [
                "start"
            ],
            "isWatching": true
        }
    ]
}
```

If you want to debug a web application you should take a look at [vscode-chrome-debug](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug) if it is a node application you have to set the entry point of your app as program in launch.json `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js"`

Comment: Thank you! So this effectively starts foreman from visual studio and gets my node.js backend running just like I wanted, but I must still be missing something, because none of my breakpoints are getting hit. I've tried `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/lib/verify/guest.js"` which is the specific file I want to test and `"program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/app.js"` which is the app.js file.


Am I still missing something?

Comment: Setting breakpoints should work if your launch.json looks like [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-configurations). Is your debugger running and is the color of the breakpoint red or gray? preLaunchTask in your launch config should be removed if the debugger is not starting.

Comment: It is also possible that a launch configuration is not working in your case because foreman is already running the app. In this case your have to create an attach configuration and attach the debugger to your running node-foreman app. `{
            "name": "Attach",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 5858,
            "address": "localhost",
            "restart": false,
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "remoteRoot": null
        }`

Comment: When I run it on `"port": 5858` it times out, which makes sense because I'm running on 3777. When I run it on `"port": 3777` the debugger controls pop up, but then disappear. If I attach to port 3777 and then run `foreman start`, the debugger tools disappear as soon as I run `foreman start`. Is there a reason that could happen? (Thanks again for your help.)

Comment: Is foreman showing any remote debugging ports in the output? if not, this might be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29071914/1787868

Comment: It wasn't. I added `webDebug: node --debug-brk=5858 bin/app.js` to the Procfile and changed the Attach to 5858 and now it's hitting the breakpoints in my app.js file, but not the file I actually need to debug. I haven't been able to figure out why that is.

Comment: Are you sure that the file you are trying to debug is in the same context as your app.js. Without more information about the app structure it's hard to say what is going wrong.

Comment: That's the thought process I needed! I changed the context to workers (the context of the code) and it worked!! Thank you so much.