# How to debug Ruby code on Visual Studio Code?

Tags: ruby, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I am new to VSCode, however, I did download the required extensions as I read in a website. So far, I can't debug Ruby on VSCode, and I am not sure where the problem lies. It just don't start... I don't think it considers the code as Ruby.
Whenever I try to run the code, I see "downloading C# extensions..." in the debugging window. Which is odd of course.
Any help?

Comment: Can you provide screenshots, or a more detailed description?

Comment: The screen shot won't help in any. The code works perfectly fine on Sublime.
I just wanna know how to debug Ruby language on VSCode?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is actually fairly easy once you follow the right steps.
First, you have to download [Ruby Extension](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby) which is available on vs code marketplace or simply via Extension tab in VS code itself: just search for Ruby, install it, and reload VS Code [update: vscode can perfectly load new extensions without needing a reload].
secondly, you have to follow the debugging guide for this extension which is available on the GitHub link I provided or in vs code marketplace. Here's the section you would be most interested in, but you could also see the [original wiki](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/wiki):

> Install Ruby Dependencies
>
> In this extension, we implement ruby debug ide protocol to allow VS
> Code to communicate with ruby debug, it requires ruby-debug-ide to be
> installed on your machine. This is also how RubyMine/NetBeans does by
> default.
>
> - If you are using JRuby or Ruby v1.8.x (jruby, ruby_18, mingw_18), run
>
>   ```
>   gem install ruby-debug-ide
>   ```
>
> The latest version is 0.6.0. Make sure `ruby-debug-base` is installed together with `ruby-debug-ide`.
>
> - If you are using Ruby v1.9.x (ruby_19, mingw_19), run
>
>   ```
>   gem install ruby-debug-ide
>   ```
>
> The latest version is 0.6.0. Make sure `ruby-debug-base19x` is installed together with `ruby-debug-ide`.
>
> - If you are using Ruby v2.x
>
>   ```
>   gem install ruby-debug-ide -v 0.6.0 (or higher versions)
>   gem install debase -v 0.2.1 (or higher versions)
>   ```
>
> Add VS Code config to your project
>
> Go to the debugger view of VS Code and hit the gear icon. Choose Ruby
> or Ruby Debugger from the prompt window, then you'll get the sample
> launch config in .vscode/launch.json. The sample launch configurations
> include debuggers for RSpec (complete, and active spec file) and
> Cucumber runs. These examples expect that bundle install --binstubs
> has been called. Detailed instruction for debugging Ruby
> Scripts/Rails/etc
>
> Read following instructions about how to debug ruby/rails/etc locally
> or remotely
>
> 01 [Debugger installation](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/wiki/1.-Debugger-Installation)

> 02 [Launching from VS Code](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/wiki/2.-Launching-from-VS-Code)

> 03 [Attaching to a debugger](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/wiki/3.-Attaching-to-a-debugger)

> 04 [Running gem scripts](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/wiki/4.-Running-gem-scripts)

> 05 [Example configurations](https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/wiki/5.-Example-configurations)

if you follow these steps, you will have every dependency installed in Step 1.
Step 2 helps you config your project workspace to start debuging codes written in ruby.
by finishing step 2, you should be able to start debugging.
here is a simple config that I use in my recent ruby project to simply debug the current open file. this is fully explained in the second step I linked

```
{
   "name": "Debug Local File",
   "type": "Ruby",
   "request": "launch",
   "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
   "program": "${file}"
}
```

"program": "${file}" is the line that enables debugging the current open file.

Comment: This works. However it suddenly stopped working for me - the error was 'no debug adapter found'. The fix was to remove all breakpoints. Then it worked again.

Comment: thanks Mahdad. any suggestions on how to use this with something like foreman where multiple processes are spawned?

Comment: @chi I personally do not have working experience with foreman, but I hope this link on SO can give you what you are looking for.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36295421/running-foreman-start-through-visual-studio-code-launch-json

Comment: How can I pass command line arguments to the debugger?

Comment: @sgX You can look at configuration examples provided; The one you looking for is the "args" property if I'm not mistaken; especially the RSpec example: https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby/wiki/5.-Example-configurations

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Ruby Debug](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=castwide.ruby-debug) extension for Visual Studio Code